# I'm stuck in boot with error messages Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, 22.04, acpi, pcie

Just moved so my computer has been in storage for a couple of months. It was running fine previously and was fine on for a couple of days since the move but now I can't get past the boot screen where I have a lot of error messages.

I've managed to update bios and Ubuntu, but neither have solved the problem.

I'd be grateful for advice:

System Information
Product Name     HP Z440 Workstation
1st Processor Type    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v3 @ 3.50GHz

Memory Size     32 GB ECC RDDR4/2133 MHZ

System Bios     M60 V02.61 03/23/2023

Boot Block Date        07/02/2014
ME Firmware Version    9.1.45.3000
ME Firmware Mode     AMT

Ubuntu 22.04.02

On boot:

```
[1.090437] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip

[ 1.094029] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip

[1.097069] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip 

[1.100440] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip

[1.104061] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip

[1.107133] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip 

[1.110064] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip

[1.113500] ima: Error Communicating to TPM chip 

[5.843992] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Attempt to CreateField of length zero (20210730/dsopcode-133)

[5.844089] ACPI Error: Aborting method SB.HMIV.HVPI due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529)

[5.8441501] ACPI Error: Aborting method SB.HMIV.HMPV due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529) 

[5.8454041] ACPI Error: Needed [Buffer/String/Package], found [Integer] 000000003f06f5c0 (20210730/exгesop-557)

[5.845469] ACPI Error: AE AHL OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Index] (20210730/dswexec-431)

[5.845548) ACPI Error: Aborting method SB.HMIV.HVPO due to previous error (AE AML OPERAND_TYPE) (20210730/psparse-529)

[5.845605] ACPI Error: Aborting method SB.HMIV.HHPV due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20210730/psparse-529)

[5.847328] ACPI Error: Needed [Buffer/String/Package], found [Integer] 0000000060f9f561 (20210730/exresop-557)

[5.847378] ACPI Error: AE AML OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Index] (20210730/dswexec-431)

[5.847456] ACPI Error: Aborting method SB.HMIV.HVPO due to previous error (AE AML OPERAND_TYPE) (20210730/psparse-529) 

[5.847516] ACPI Error: Aborting method SB.HMIV.HHPV due to previous error (AE AML OPERAND_TYPE) (20210730/psparse-529)

[5.847673] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Attempt to CreateField of length zero (20210730/dsopcode-133) 

[5.847723] ACPI Error: Aborting method SB.HMIV.WVPI due to previous error (AE AML OPERAND_VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529) 

[5.847757] ACPI Error: Aborting method SB.WMIV.HMPV due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND VALUE) (20210730/psparse-529) 

[6.183510]  usb 3-5: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
```

Comment: Does it boot up after the error messages?

Comment: No it doesnt. Just hangs on the error screen until Pr Scr + B

Comment: Is it possible a onboard connector could of loosened up while moving the machine? TPM is some kind of security chipset and the other regards usb/storage devices. There are many possibilities. One being a hardware issue, loose connection. I'm hoping there will be others who will add to this subject.